# How to update more than one table in one update statement

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2005

I am updating one column in a table from details view control of .net 3.5 and using SQL Server 2005

The problem is I have to update same column in 5 more tables in the same database but have to use single database

Is it possible?

please let me know the SQL query syntax form update if possible.

Comment: I do not know if its possible. based on my knowledge, one update is for 1 table, you can put several update(s) in one transaction or stored procedure, but fundamentally, one update for 1 table

Answer (score 4):

You can't update 5 different tables in one update query.

You can write a stored procedure that updates that 5 tables and call that procedure once.

Answer (score 1):

There are work arounds.

1. create a view such that it has 5 table joins and a select statement on 5 columns. Then update the view.
2. Write update trigger on table 1 and in the trigger write update for table2...continue.

I have not tried this before, so just first give a try.